# Error: Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs

×
Error: llamada de gancho no válida. Los ganchos solo se pueden llamar dentro del cuerpo de un componente de función. Esto podría suceder por una de las siguientes razones:

1. Es posible que tenga versiones no coincidentes de React y el renderizador (como React DOM)
2. Es posible que esté infringiendo las Reglas de Hooks
3. Es posible que tenga más de una copia de React en la misma aplicación
   Consulte https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call para obtener consejos sobre cómo depurar y solucionar este problema.

Alguien me ayuda por favor? ya consulté con la página pero no me resulve el error.

Comment: Hola, comparte tu código y date un paseo por este articulo para evitar que tus preguntas sean eliminadas y a la vez puedas obtener una mejor ayuda por parte de la comunidad https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask