# Como hago para que no me de error este código React@17.0.2?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Quisiera que alguien me pueda ayudar con este error en React.

> Error: llamada de gancho no válida. Los ganchos solo se pueden llamar
> dentro del cuerpo de un componente de función. Esto podría suceder por
> una de las siguientes razones:
>
> 1. Es posible que tenga versiones no coincidentes de React y el renderizador (como React DOM)
> 2. Puede que esté infringiendo las reglas de los Hooks
> 3. Es posible que tenga más de una copia de React en la misma aplicación Consulte https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call para
>    obtener consejos sobre cómo depurar y solucionar este problema.

Mas detalles del error:

```
▼ 30 stack frames were expanded.
resolveDispatcher
C: /Users/Caleb99/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js: 1476
useContext
C: /Users/Caleb99/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js: 1484
useParams
C: / Users / Caleb99 / Documents / proyectos react / modules / hooks.js: 40
MovieDetails
C: / Users / Caleb99 / Documents / proyectos react / virgen / src / pages / MovieDetails.jsx: 7
renderWithHooks
C: / Users / Caleb99 / Documents / proyectos react / virgen / node_modules / react-dom / cjs / react-dom.development.js: 14985
mountIndeterminateComponent
C: / Users / Caleb99 / Documents / proyectos react / virgen / node_modules / react-dom / cjs / react-dom.development.js: 17811
beginWork
C: / Users / Caleb99 / Documents / proyectos react / virgen / node_modules / react-dom / cjs / react-dom.development.js: 19049
HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback
C: / Users / Caleb99 / Documents / proyectos react / virgen / node_modules / react-dom / cjs / react-dom.development.js: 3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev
C: / Users / Caleb99 / Documents / proyectos react / virgen / node_modules / react-dom / cjs / react-dom.development.js: 3994
invokeGuardedCallback
C: / Users / Caleb99 / Documents / proyectos react / virgen / node_modules / react-dom / cjs / react-dom.development.js: 4056
beginWork $ 1
C: / Users / Caleb99 / Documents / proyectos react / virgen / node_modules / react-dom / cjs / react-dom.development.js: 23964
performUnitOfWork
C: / Users / Caleb99 / Documents / proyectos react / virgen / node_modules / react-dom / cjs / react-dom.development.js: 22776
```

He leido mucho acerca de hooks pero aun no logro identificar el error. La linea que muestra error es esta:

```
    import React from "react";
    import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { useParams } from "react-router";
    import { get } from "../utils/httpClient";
    import styles from "./MovieDetails.module.css";
    
    export function MovieDetails() {
      const { movieId } = useParams(); //----> aqui se explota la app por este hooks importado
      const [movie, setMovie] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        get("/movie/" + movieId).then((data) => {
          setMovie(data);
        });
      }, [movieId]);
    
      if (!movie) {
        return null;
      }
    
      const imageUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + movie.poster_path;
      return (
        <div className={styles.detailsContainer}>
          <img
            className={`${styles.col} ${styles.movieImage}`}
            src={imageUrl}
            alt={movie.title}
          />
          <div className={`${styles.col} ${styles.movieDetails}`}>
            <p className={styles.firstItem}>
              <strong>Title:</strong> {movie.title}
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Genres:</strong>{" "}
              {movie.genres.map((genre) => genre.name).join(", ")}
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Description:</strong> {movie.overview}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Aqui llamo al componente:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./App.module.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { MovieDetails } from "./pages/MovieDetails";
import { LandingPage } from "./pages/LandingPage";

export function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <header>
        <Link to="/">
          <h1 className={styles.title}>Movies</h1>
        </Link>
      </header>
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/movies/:movieId">
            <MovieDetails />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <LandingPage />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Detalles de React: npm ls react

```
+-- react-dom@17.0.2
| `-- react@17.0.2
+-- react-icons@4.3.1
| `-- react@17.0.2 deduped
+-- react-infinite-scroll-component@6.1.0
| `-- react@17.0.2 deduped
`-- react-router-dom@5.3.0
  +-- react-router@5.2.1
  | +-- mini-create-react-context@0.4.1
  | | `-- react@17.0.2 deduped
  | `-- react@17.0.2 deduped
  `-- react@17.0.2 deduped
```

Soy nuevo en react, les agradeceria la ayuda.

Comment: Mueve  `const { movieId } = useParams(); `, colócalo en la siguiente línea después de `useState`, te sugiero agregar el componente completo a la pregunta, saludos

Comment: Puedes agregar el componente completo para poder analizar mejor el problema

Comment: Listo amigos , ya añadi el componente completo. El hooks importado que uso lo he colocado en la parte superior de la función, como lo enseña la la documentación de react.

Comment: Será bueno mencionar en la pregunta que estas usando react 17 ¿Qué versión de `react-router` estas usando? también agrega eso; será de utilidad si agregas el componente donde esta el `Route` que tiene como `path` `MovieDetails`, para ver si se están pasando los parámetros correctamente.

Comment: muy bien amigo. Ya actualice los datos.

Comment: Ya hubo [una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495083/error-invalid-hook-call) en esta semana con el mismo problema,  ¿Estas usando el template `create-react-app`?

Comment: Amigo, yo creo el proyecto con este comando npx create-react-app my-app. Es la forma que recomienda facebook.

Comment: El error que me aparece se parece mucho a este: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69236642/change-code-to-use-uselocation-instead-of-routercontext-i-now-have-invalid-ho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos por fin encontré la solución de mi problema!!!

La comparto para que ayude a otro novato que le pueda pasar lo mismo y se ahorre dos días de lio e investigación jjj.

El error se debía a que al parecer React no encontraba el paquete react-router-dom, aunque estaba instalado(lo instale y desinstale muchas veces intentando resolver el lio). Lo solucione haciendo un `cd` dentro de la carpeta donde esta alojado el proyecto y posterior a eso un `npm i` o `npm install` (es lo mismo) y luego `npm start`. listo problema resuelto!!!

Es necesario revisar que estén todas las dependencias en el package.json del proyecto previo a ejecutar comando `npm i`.

Este problema se puede presentar sobre todo cuando transladas un proyecto de un pc a otro.

Listo amigos, Dios bendiga a todos los que me intentaron ayudar. Muchas bendiciones a todos!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para que React reconozca que se está definiendo un componente funcional tiene que estar importado `react` (el export por defecto) al inicio del archivo. Si no, entonces al transpilar interpreta el archivo como una función y no un componente de React.

Añádelo al hacer los imports:

```javascript
import react, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router";
import { get } from "../utils/httpClient";
import styles from "./MovieDetails.module.css";

export function MovieDetails() {
  const { movieId } = useParams(); //----> aqui se explota la app por este hooks importado
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    get("/movie/" + movieId).then((data) => {
      setMovie(data);
    });
  }, [movieId]);

  if (!movie) {
    return null;
  }

  const imageUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500" + movie.poster_path;
  return (
    <div className={styles.detailsContainer}>
      <img
        className={`${styles.col} ${styles.movieImage}`}
        src={imageUrl}
        alt={movie.title}
      />
      <div className={`${styles.col} ${styles.movieDetails}`}>
        <p className={styles.firstItem}>
          <strong>Title:</strong> {movie.title}
        </p>
        <p>
          <strong>Genres:</strong>{" "}
          {movie.genres.map((genre) => genre.name).join(", ")}
        </p>
        <p>
          <strong>Description:</strong> {movie.overview}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: amigo, segun entendi me indicates que añadiera lo siquiente al codigo:            import React from 'react';  Para que react lo identificara como un componente. Lo hice y sigue dando el mismo error. Estoy usando react 17 y tengo entendido que en esta versión ya no es necesario hacer las importaciones de react como lo eran en las otras versiones.